# What does a second specified type mean in a template typename declaration?

Tags: c++, templates

I am comfortable with templating functions and classes but I didn't know what to make of this when I saw it. I am sure its probably everyday syntax to most but I would like to get a well clarified explanation if anyone has one for me. What does the second uint32-t max mean and how is it used in the templated type?

Heres the syntax:

```
template <typename T, uint32_t max>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In it a non-type template parameter. See [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) for a real life example where it is used to define the size of the array.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a second parameter to the template.  And template parameters don't have to be types.  They can be constants or templates as well.  Thus, given

```
template <typename T, uint32_t max> class TC {};
```

you would instantiate it:

```
TC< MyClass, 42 > t;
```

(for example.)  Similarly, if it is a function template:

```
template <typename T, uint32_t max> void tf( T (&array)[max] );
```

type deduction can be used to determine the (numeric) value of `max`.

Such value templates cannot have just any type; it must be an
integral type or a pointer or reference.

Comment: In the OP's example this could for example be a template for a container for T with given maximum capacity.

Comment: @PeterK Or anything else.  His question seemed more general.

Answer (score 10):

The second parameter is a `uint32_t` rather than a type.  For example it might specify the number of elements in an array.

```
template <typename T, uint32_t max>
struct Array
{
    T data[max];
};

/* ... */

// usage example 
Array<double, 10> a;
```

Answer (score 8):

It's so you can specify a non-type value as a template argument.

A good example is [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), which has two template arguments, the type of the contained data and the size of the array.

For example

```
std:array<int, 256> my_array;
```

Do note that you can't use any types as value template arguments, it's basically limited to pointers, references and integer values.

Comment: Re the last sentence: and references.  (Yet another way that references behave like pointers under the hood.)

Answer (score 5):

You can use types, integral values, or even templates as template parameters. There are lots of reasons why and how this could be used, and it's impossible to tell you what it does in your specific case.

For example, consider this function that returns the pointer to the end of an array (analogue to `std::end` for C arrays in C++11):

```
template <typename T, size_t k>
T * end(T (& arr)[k])
{
    return arr + k;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The second `uint32_t max` means, that when instantiating the template, you have to pass a second template argument of type `uint32_t` that is known at compile time.